# Random choice not working in this case?

Tags: python, list, random

I'm trying to make it so I get random choice out of an list of players... It's fairly simple, I know, but I can't get it to work, I get some random letters, like "i" or "e" as result :O

Here's that part of code:

```
print "p.getName()", p.getName()
randomtarget = choice(p.getName())
```

p is a list of players, getName is function to get their names, I get them successfully, so this is what I got:

```
22:29:21 [INFO] p.getName() Brixishuge
22:29:21 [INFO] Random target: i
```

obviously, random target should be "Brixishuge", since it's only possible target, but I get "i" as result, why? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't call choice with a list of strings, the method takes as input a string and thus returns characters of that string (the elements). Built an array first and then feed it to the `choice` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

random.choice takes a list of things to choose from.

Since you are giving it just a string (`p.getName()` returns a string) it is treating the string
as a list of characters, from which it is choosing a character ('i' in your case.)

You probably meant this:

```
randomtarget = choice([p.getName()])
```

You can make a list either by putting something in square brackets or by calling the list function.

```
l = [p.getName()]
l = list(p.getName())
```

Apon further reading, it apears that p is not a list of players but one single player.

If you want the name of a random player you should try this:

```
player = choice(list_of_players)
name = player.getName()
```

Comment: This works like a charm! :) I just saw that I forgot to tell python to make it listed in getName function :D Thank you very much for pointing that out for me, it really helped :)

Comment: @user2971511 If this answer helped you it would be good to accept it at some point.

Comment: @sweeneyrod I actually did now, couldn't do it before since I have to wait approx. 10 min after question to accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

Your input to choice must be a list so that you will return one of the elements of that list.  Here you are putting in a string so that choice will return one of the characters of that string.

```
import random
p = ['Brixishuge', 'user2971511', 'sabbahillel']
random.choice(p)
```

If your input was ['Brixishuge'] it would work the way you expect.

[Python Number choice() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_choice.htm)

> Description The method choice() returns a random item from a list,
>   tuple, or string.
>
> Syntax Following is the syntax for choice() method:
>
> choice( seq ) Note: This function is not accessible directly, so we
>   need to import random module and then we need to call this function
>   using random static object.
>
> Parameters seq -- This could be a list, tuple, or string...
>
> Return Value This method returns a random item.